# Is there any way to check smooth scroll in UITests

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode-ui-testing, smooth-scrolling

I created an UI test that load thousands of entries in a tableview. I use the next code to scroll the table view:

```
let table = app.tables.element
table.swipeUp()
table.swipeUp()
table.swipeUp()
```

Is there any way to check if the scoll is smooth?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to test if scrolling of a table view is smooth with a UITest.

`XCTest` offers performance tests but they are meant for UnitTests only. You can test how performant your code is but not your UI.

You can [use Instruments to monitor the frame rate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH32-SW1) in you app. Launch the app with Instruments and scroll your table view. If the frame rate drops significantly you have a performance bottleneck.

BTW the scrolling performance of a `UITableView` should not be different for 10 cells or 10000 cells, because the cells are reused.